# Dealing with optional dependencies (C#)

Tags: c#, dependencies

We have an app which optionally integrates with TFS, however as the integration is optional I obviously **don't want to have all machine need the TFS assemblies as a requirement**.

What should I do?

1. Is it ok for me to reference the TFS libraries in my main assemblies and just make sure that I only reference TFS related objects when I'm using TFS integration.
2. Alternatively the safer option would be to reference the TFS libraries in some separate "TFSWrapper" assembly:

   a. Is it then ok for me to reference that assembly directly (again as long as I'm careful about what I call)

   b. Should I instead be exposing a set of interfaces for my TFSWrapper assembly to implement, and then instantiate those objects using reflection when required.

1 seems risky to me, on the flip side 2b seems over-the-top - I would essentially be building a plug-in system.

Surely there must be a simpler way.

Comment: "TFS" in this case is "Team Foundation System," right?

Comment: Yes, but I consider the question to be less about TFS and more with the best way to reference assemblies which might not be present on some users machines.

Comment: D'oh, I didn't read the first sentence carefully enough, so I didn't realize that by 'optional' you meant 'may not be present on the user's machine.'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The safest way (i.e. the easiest way to not make a mistake in your application) might be as follows.

Make an interface which abstracts your use of TFS, for example:

```
interface ITfs
{
  bool checkout(string filename);
}
```

Write a class which implements this interface using TFS:

```
class Tfs : ITfs
{
  public bool checkout(string filename)
  {
    ... code here which uses the TFS assembly ...
  }
}
```

Write another class which implements this interface without using TFS:

```
class NoTfs : ITfs
{
  public bool checkout(string filename)
  {
    //TFS not installed so checking out is impossible
    return false;
  }
}
```

Have a singleton somewhere:

```
static class TfsFactory
{
  public static ITfs instance;

  static TfsFactory()
  {
    ... code here to set the instance
    either to an instance of the Tfs class
    or to an instance of the NoTfs class ...
  }
}
```

Now there's only one place which needs to be careful (i.e. the TfsFactory constructor); the rest of your code can invoke the ITfs methods of your TfsFactory.instance without knowing whether TFS is installed.

---

To answer recent comments below:

According to my tests (I don't know whether this is 'defined behaviour') an exception is thrown when (as soon as) you call a method which depends on the missing assembly. Therefore it's important to encapsulate your code-which-depends-on-the-missing-assembly in at least a separate method (or a separate class) in your assembly.

For example, the following won't load if the Talk assembly is missing:

```
using System;
using OptionalLibrary;

namespace TestReferences
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "1") {
                Talk talk = new Talk();
                Console.WriteLine(talk.sayHello() + " " + talk.sayWorld() + "!");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("2 Hello World!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following will load:

```
using System;
using OptionalLibrary;

namespace TestReferences
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "1") {
                foo();
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("2 Hello World!");
            }
        }

        static void foo()
        {
            Talk talk = new Talk();
            Console.WriteLine(talk.sayHello() + " " + talk.sayWorld() + "!");
        }
    }
}
```

These are the test results (using MSVC# 2010 and .NET on Windows):

```
C:\github\TestReferences\TestReferences\TestReferences\bin\Debug>TestReferences.exe
2 Hello World!

C:\github\TestReferences\TestReferences\TestReferences\bin\Debug>TestReferences.exe 1

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'OptionalLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at TestReferences.MainClass.foo()
   at TestReferences.MainClass.Main(String[] args) in C:\github\TestReferences\TestReferences\TestReferences\Program.cs:
line 11

C:\github\TestReferences\TestReferences\TestReferences\bin\Debug>
```

Comment: But your saying that its ok if the implementation of the Tfs class lives inside the same assembly?

Comment: Using the traditional Windows API, if you link to a DLL which doesn't exist on the end-user machine then your executable won't load at all: and so, instead, you need to use explicit LoadLibrary. I'm not certain that I've tested this, but I don't believe that's true anymore of dotNet references to assemblies which don't exist on the end-user machine ... and so it's safe to have those references in your assembly (there'll be a run-time exception only when/if you try to call the non-existent assembly).

Comment: That would make TfsFactory depend on the assembly containing Tfs class. And since TfsFactory is used in the application, it will still require to distribute the software with "optional" Tfs dll. :-)

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that you need the DLL in order to build, but that you can ship/deploy without it ... and that if it isn't present on the target machine, the assembly will still load, and that everything (except the TfsFactory method) will run correctly.

Comment: @ChrisW: Nope. I tested it. Even if the code using the TfsFactory doesn't execute, the application still fails to run due to a missing DLL. P.S. I tested this with Mono, maybe it's different in .NET.

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov I just tested it too (using .NET not Mono). The application starts, but I get an exception when I call a method whose implementation depends on an undefined type. So it should work if your `if` statement prevents the method being called, and may not work if your `if` statement guard is inside the method which contains code that depends on the type.

Comment: @ChrisW Just tried that with VS2010. Same result as with Mono. It must be something that I'm doing differently than you. Here is my test solution: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16259710/TestReferences.7z. Try deleting OptionalLibrary.dll from Binaries folder and running the program. This should not trigger the code that depends on that library, which is only executed when "1" is passed as first parameter. Despite this, on my machine, it still fails with an FileNotFoundException.

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov Move your Talk-dependent code into a separate method e.g. like this: `class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "1") {
                foo();
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("2 Hello World!");
            }
        }

        static void foo()
        {
            Talk talk = new Talk();
            Console.WriteLine(talk.sayHello() + " " + talk.sayWorld() + "!");
        }
    }`

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov In the test results given above, note that the exception doesn't come from Line 1 of the foo method ... it comes from (trying to JIT) the foo method itself. Therefore you don't want that code inside your Main method.

Comment: @ChrisW It was interesting too know. Indeed, once the dependant code is in a separate method, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) (MEF).

Comment: That does look pretty interesting, although possibly a little over the top for what I'm doing at the moment!
I'll probably take a look later though.

Answer (score 0):

A "plug-in" concept may be the way to go, and it may also allow you to (later) extend your application to work with other products than TFS if needed. Option 2a will be just as "risky" (failing when the linked files are missing) as option 1.

You can make an assembly with the required interfaces for your specific purpose, and reference this assembly from both your app and the "TFS plug-in". The latter then provides implementations of your interfaces and uses TFS to perform the operations. The app can dynamically load an assembly and create instances of the plug-in types needed (via [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) etc.) and cast those instances to your interfaces.

In fact, if you make those types inherit from [MarshalByRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx), you could even load them into another [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) and thus make a clean separation of your plugins, and also make them unloadable.

Comment: I am actually trying to implement a plug-in system. However, sometimes I would like to use a type introduced in another assembly. The code using this type will be guarded with an "if" statement that will guarantee that it's only used when the library is available and loaded. Is there a way to do this in C#?

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov, yes this can be done, but only through late binding (e.g. Reflection or dynamic). If the type can implement some interface which is always available it will make it more convenient to use.