# Implementing Interface using Reflection c#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a requirement where I need to implement an interface in my project which is present in a third part DLL. I'm loading this DLL using reflection. Is it Possible?

```
class MyClass : I3rdPartyInterface
{
    //implementing interface   
}
```

Here, the `I3rdPartyInterface` is the interface present in my 3rd Party DLL.
This DLL could, or could not, be present on Client machine my software product is installed. If it is present, then i should implement the interface methods.

Comment: Why you are loading this DLL using reflection? Why you couldn't reference it?

Comment: @xtnd8 Yes exactly i can't refer this Dll in my project

Comment: what is the problem you face with this? Is this unmanaged DLL?

Comment: You *can* generate code at runtime that implements it by emitting IL: libraries do this to make proxy classes. This is pretty darn complex though.

Comment: Are you *sure* you can't add a reference to this DLL? Why not? You don't need source code to add a reference.

Comment: the 3rd party Dll is .NET Dll

Comment: @Anamay And WHY you could not reference this library?

Comment: @Blorgbeard See the Dll doesn't belong to my Product ,Its say could my Product competitors dlls , so it could or could not be there in client (users) machine.Also if it is present then I am implementing some APIs which implements that interface.

Comment: In that case just add a reference to the 3rd party dll. If using Visual Studio right click on references, select Add Reference then select Browse. Select the DLL then your add the correct using statement and your code above should work.

Comment: All of the referenced DLLs will be included in your deployment folder.

Comment: @user2981639 please see my previous comment why i can't refer the dll in my Project

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is - you can always reference any .NET DLL in your project when you build it. If later when a user tries to run the code and the dll you referenced is not available you'll get a runtime error but that's normal?

Comment: @Anamay Have you tried it? From what I've read, you'll only run into issues once you try to use the specific code that uses the dll. A good way to go might be to detect if the dll is there: if it isn't, don't use the parts of your code that require it.

Comment: This might be a good resource if you can't think of a way to avoid using parts of the code that are "tainted" by references to the optional dll. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1422271/382780](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1422271/382780)

Comment: @31eee384 Intitally I have done the same.Like looking up for the dLL and loading it in specific app domains

Comment: @Anamay So what went wrong? Maybe you could ask that question instead.

Comment: @31eee384 : see the scenario is third party dLL could be present or not in client machine ,If it is not present i would not be able to build my Project.If I use reflection i can handle this situation by restricting the Dll loading to a specific app domain,This is the reason why using reflection is suited in my scenario

Comment: You don't need to build on your client machine, right? They're just running the .exe, and at runtime you can safely decide whether or not your code should use the code that depends on the DLL. I think you're making some assumptions that make the easiest solution seem impossible to you.

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to write a new project that references that dll and implements the interface - and load that in runtime.

The new dll "translates" between the external dll types and your application's types - that way there is no direct dependency between your app and the external dll.

You can generate and compile code at runtime but for this scenario it's just simpler to create a wrapper/translator dll

Comment: Exactly the same thought i got .Let me see how Feasible is this in my senario.Thanks alot for you suggestion.The wrapper stuff can solve this.